# Duplicate all rows in a table and prevent duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, sql, clone, temp-tables

I am tring to do this

- Get all rows in a blogs named table.
- Copy them in a temporary database
- Edit the language field of this temporary table records
- Insert into the blogs table

And I'm trying it like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE lan = 2;
UPDATE tmptable SET lan = 1;
INSERT INTO blogs SELECT * FROM tmptable; dump database tmptable;
```

But of corse I get duplicated key error...

How Can I prevent it?

-EDIT-

I TRIED:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE lan = 2;
UPDATE tmptable SET lan = 1;
ALTER TABLE tmptable DROP id;
INSERT INTO blogs SELECT * FROM tmptable; dump database tmptable;
```

But then the `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

-EDIT-

I believe this will work  (And it Did, cause I know how many records exist)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE lan = 2;
UPDATE tmptable SET lan = 1;
UPDATE tmptable SET id = id + 1000;
INSERT INTO blogs SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```

But how can I do it properly? (just set the next avaliable autoincrement value for primary key(id) (without PHP/alike))

-EDIT-

maybe something like this???

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE lan = 2;
UPDATE tmptable SET lan = 1;
UPDATE tmptable SET id = id + (SELECT id FROM blogs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO blogs SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```

Comment: the id of the blogs table is an identity?

Comment: its the primary key, unique and autoincrement. yes!

Comment: Why not just change your INSERT statement to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE lan = 2;
UPDATE tmptable SET lan = 1;
alter table tmptable drop column id;
INSERT INTO blogs SELECT NULL,tmptable.* FROM tmptable;
```

Assumed, the column "id" is the first col.

Answer (score 17):

No temporary table needed.

```
INSERT INTO blogs (lan, col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT 1, col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM blogs
WHERE lan = 2
```

Replace `col1, col2, col3, ...` with a list of all columns except `lan` and `id`.

Comment: Is this something you have to do often? Does your table schema change much? If so, you could write a stored procedure that generates the SQL dynamically from information_schema.

Comment: Visual query tools/designers will make SQL for you that includes a list of all fields with a few clicks. Can then cut/paste as needed to make your INSERT etc.

Comment: I just want to say thank you for being a noncomformist and really thinking about the most appropriate solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE blogs SET lan = 1 WHERE lan = 2;
```

Simply run that query on your original table.

> I don't want to change the language, I want to save another copy of
>   all the records and asign this copies a different language

In that case, drop the primary key from your temporary table. When you insert back the rows, don't include the primary key column:

```
INSERT INTO blogs (title, lan) SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```

Comment: NOOOOOO.... I don't want to change the language, I want to save another copy of all the records and asign this copies a different language

Answer (score 1):

Please try following sql. A similar    [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f019/1)

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE lan = 2;
    UPDATE tmptable SET lan = 1;
    UPDATE tmptable SET id = (select @val:=@val+1 from(select @val:=(select max(id) from blogs)) t)
    INSERT INTO blogs SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared statement you can query the information schema for the column you want to use and then forge the query you want to execute:

here an example for your case:

```
-- first query all the blogs column minus id and lan

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME)
INTO @cols
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE
 c.TABLE_NAME = 'blogs'
 AND c.COLUMN_NAME not in ('id', 'lan');

-- second build the query with the gathered columns
-- like INSERT INTO blogs(lan, col1, ...) SELECT 2, col1, ... FROM blogs WHERE lan=1

SET @sql=CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('INSERT INTO blogs (lan,', @cols), 
                ') SELECT 2,'), @cols), ' FROM blogs WHERE lan=1');

-- prepare the statement    
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

-- and last run the insert
EXECUTE stmt;
```